# merge list of nested list to a single list which has lakhs of data python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a list which looks like

```
[['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username'],
 ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username', 'name'],
 ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username'],
 ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username','country':'india']]
```

The above is the sample which consists of 4 data only. In my case, I can have thousands of entries which is similar to the above.

I want to compare the data of the list and merge the list to one single list.

Required:

```
['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username', 'name', 'country']
```

How to make it possible and get the output faster?

Comment: `'country':'india'` at the end of the list gives a syntax error.

Comment: The last element of your list `country: india` is not rightly formatted. This type of question comes when you don't try. What you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. i corrected it.

Comment: What code did you write - edit it into your question.

Comment: I think there are many articles on flattening sublists into lists. But people do not check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

l =  [['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username'], ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username', 'name'], ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username'],['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username','country']]
list(set(chain(*l)))
```

Output -

```
['username', '_rev', '_id', 'name', 'password', 'country']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dict.fromkeys` and flattening the list:

```
print(list(dict.fromkeys([x for i in l for x in i])))
```

Or `set` with `sorted`:

```
flat = [x for i in l for x in i]
print(sorted(set(flat), key=flat.index))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code

```
l =  [['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username'], ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username', 'name'], ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username'],['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username','country']]

ll = []
for i in l:
    ll.extend(i)

#Remove dupes
gl = list(set(ll))

print(gl)
```

Output

```
['username', '_id', 'name', 'country', '_rev', 'password']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution !

```
arr = [['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username'], ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username', 'name'], ['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username'],['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username','country']]

new_arr = arr[0]

for i in range(1,len(arr)):
    for j in range(0,len(arr[i])):
        if not arr[i][j] in new_arr:
            new_arr.append(arr[i][j])

print(new_arr)
```

**Output :**

```
['password', '_rev', '_id', 'username', 'name', 'country']
```